# parallel uniform distribution pseudorandom namber using OpenMP

Tags: c++, boost, random, openmp

i use in my program boost uniform distribution between 0 and 1:

```
 #include <boost/random/uniform_01.hpp>
 #include <boost/random.hpp>

 static boost::mt19937 rng;
 static boost::uniform_01<boost::mt19937&> zeroone(rng);
```

`zeroone()` function is called inside a for-loop which i would like to parallel, using OpenMP.

```
 for ( int index = 0 ; index < 4096 ; index++ ) {
     if ( node[ index ] == false ) {
        if ( zeroone() < 0.03 )
           node[ index ] = true;
      }
 }
```

The question if it is possible using OpenMP to parallel the `for-loop` and not damaging the uniform distribution pseudorandom number generator?

e.g. Is it possible to define for the first core a seed, for the second core the corresponding seed that the first core pseudorandom number generator will reach after 6 times?

Regards

Comment: Do you need the behaviour to be deterministic based on the initial seed of your RNG? I think the random number generators are generally thread-safe, you just can't necessarily recreate the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Kerrek: boost random generators are specifically not thread safe; Also note that my approach will enable determistic results if you (a) seed the same value (b) chunk the loop up deterministically

Comment: @sehe: What do you mean by "not thread safe" -- can the program actually just break down completely, or does this just refer to the predictability of the results?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: as I've accidentally witnessed myself in the past, the program can and will just completely crash

Comment: @sehe: I see. Good to know, and sorry for my broken claim! Do you know about the new `<random>` in C++0x, though, is it the same?

Comment: I haven't tried the new random; I presume it isn't thread safe either ((a) because tr1/c++0x seem mostly inspired by Boost (b) the standard historically doesn't specify anything about threadsafety; [this is only partially changing with c++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Multitasking_memory_model))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you suggest, but

1. it would be insane...ly inefficient (because the purpose of a RNG is to generate hard-to-predict pseudo random sequences, the only way to .... **predict** the *n<sup>th</sup>* successor would be to generate the intervening ones as well.)
2. most likely unnecessary:

You can give each thread it's own private RNG (seed each one independently). The uniform distribution property will still hold unless your dataset is really small (in which case, the uniformness would be swamped by the sample noise anyway, regardless of threads)

My scheme would look something like this:

```
typedef boost::.... rng_t;
static rng_t g_rng; // notice how you never seed this, is this on purpose?

#per thread
{
     rng_t rng(g_rng()); // need synchronized access to g_rng here
     boost::uniform_01<boost::mt19937&> zeroone(rng);

     // ...
}
```

Comment: @Luc Danton: +1 for simplicity :)

Comment: @sehe, i am able to seed it, using `rng.seed( some number )` since i use `mt19937&`...

Comment: @Eagle: subtle! I missed that. Nice way to do that

Comment: @sehe, lets say i follow your idea, so inside each thread i will have uniform distribution numbers. The question is if i compare it with the all system, will it still be close to uniform distribution?

Comment: Not close, uniform. Uniform means unbiased, it doesn't say: I'm going to be uniform when used for 400 samples in one go. It also doesn't say: I'm uniform, but I'm more uniform than another uniform distribution.

Comment: I wanted to check. It seems RNGTS and libdieharder should do the job but I can't at the moment get them to work. If you are paranoid, you should use these tests to confirm your sanity. Note that [Boost Random contains statistical tests as well](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/random/test/)

Comment: @sehe, thanks for your help. I am not paranoid, but like to know if what i would like my program to do, is also what it does ;)

Comment: Eagle: as a matter of fact, I think you should be paranoid. Good programmers are lazy _and_ paranoid :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for my C++ random number library, RandomLib, contains
an illustration of using parallel number streams in OpenMP; see
http://randomlib.sourceforge.net/html/parallel.html.  You might be
able to adapt the ideas presented there to your application.